# Data conversion and encoding CP037

Tags: events, encoding, ibm-mq, mainframe

My system reads data from `Websphere MQ` which comes from `Mainframe` queues, the data which application reads is in EBCDIC format -

It was working fine earlier, we moved to jdk1.6 earlier this year (Not sure if this cause this issue).

Am getting one variable value as 40 which EBCDIC representation of " ", but that's not getting covert.

So the question is MQ or Mainframe should responsible for this conversion? Cause we are doing below conversion but that's not working -

```
                        UnicodeFormat = "CP037";
                        byte[] b;
                        b = UninterpretedRowdata.getBytes("Cp037");
                        //System.out.println("DEST CP : "+UnicodeFormat);
                        UnicodedRow = new String(b, UnicodeFormat);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This post was actually made before the one it's being marked as a duplicate of; that post was migrated here. I deleted that one; please don't close this as a duplicate of that, folks. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why in the world you would want to do the conversion yourself.  Weird.  It is far, far better for MQ to do the conversion for you.  i.e. RTM  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/zd00050_.htm

For MQ to do the conversion requires 2 things:

1) The message needs the MD.Format field to be set to MQC.MQFMT_STRING

2) You issue a MQGet API call with convert

i.e.

```
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
gmo.options = MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT;
MQMessage receiveMsg = new MQMessage();
inQ.get(receiveMsg, gmo);
```

Comment: Thanks for checking this... We are using JMS here.. will check same settings in JMS. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following code that transforms encoding:

```
public class Converter{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Charset charsetEBCDIC = Charset.forName("CP037");
        Charset charsetACSII = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");

        String ebcdic = "(((((((";
        System.out.println("String EBCDIC: " + ebcdic);
        System.out.println("String converted to ASCII: " + convertTO(ebcdic, charsetEBCDIC, charsetACSII));

        String ascII = "MMMMMM";
        System.out.println("String ASCII: " + ascII);
        System.out.println("String converted to EBCDIC: " + convertTO(ascII, charsetACSII, charsetEBCDIC));
    }

    public static String convertTO(String dados, Charset encondingFrom, Charset encondingTo) {
        return new String(dados.getBytes(encondingFrom), encondingTo);
    }
}
```